# Android Smack 4.2 : "XMPPError: feature-not-implemented - cancel" (Error)

Tags: android, openfire, smack

I am trying to retrieve the `Archived Messages From OpenFire`

Please Note :

1. I have added the Archive Message Plugin.
2. Same code was working fine Locally, no throwing error for server installation for openfire.
3. I have gone through all the solutions provided on internet but failed to succeed.
4. I can see the archived messages in openfire panel.

below is the code to retrieve the messages :

```
public MamManager.MamQueryResult getArchivedMessages() {
        //org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$XMPPErrorException: XMPPError: feature-not-implemented - cancel
        try {
            MamManager mamManager = MamManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
            boolean isSupported = mamManager.isSupportedByServer();
            if (isSupported) {
                MamManager.MamQueryResult mamQueryResult = mamManager.pageAfter(JidCreate.from(mUsername + SERVICE_NAME), "2r2Vf-68", 250);
                List<Forwarded> forwardedMessages = mamQueryResult.forwardedMessages;
                Forwarded d = forwardedMessages.get(0);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Other then this I am also trying to implement the `OfflineMessageManager` for `smack 4.2`

below is the code for the offline maanger :

```
   public static void handleOfflineMessages() throws Exception {
        OfflineMessageManager offlineMessageManager = new OfflineMessageManager(getConnection());

        if (!offlineMessageManager.supportsFlexibleRetrieval()) {
            return;
        }

        if (offlineMessageManager.getMessageCount() == 0) {
            String d = "ss";
        } else {
            List<Message> msgs = offlineMessageManager.getMessages();
            for (Message msg : msgs) {
                BareJid fullJid = msg.getFrom().asBareJid();
                String messageBody = msg.getBody();
                if (messageBody != null) {

                }
            }
            // offlineMessageManager.deleteMessages();
        }

    }
```

> Note : The above method is not throwing any error my I am always
>   getting the message count = 0. where as I am following the official
>   Doc for this. i.e not sending presence so as to get all offline
>   messages. but failed to do so.
>
> this is the link for official doc : [OfflineMessageManager](http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/)

can anyone point what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Regarding MAM Feature Not Implemented, Can you mention the versions of Openfire, Archive Plugin and Smack which you are using?

Comment: Regarding Offline Messages, Have you confirmed that your offline messages are actually being stored on server? Are you able to check the messages in Openfire Database?

Comment: Version for my Archive Plugin is :  `Monitors conversations and statistics of the server : 1.5.7:
IgniteRealtime // Jive Software`

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to verify where the offline messages are stored in openfire database, can you please tell me how do I check and where is the option

Comment: I have added Database Access plugin and I am trying to get the database but I see null in every databse

Comment: If you are using MySQL as database, then offline messages are stored in ofOffline table.
Also, visit this URL from Openfire Admin: /offline-messages.jsp
It will show the size of currently stored offline messages and also you can check what message policy is configured here. Either it's Store or Bounce or Drop?

Comment: It is showing me `Current size of all offline message: 0.00 MB`

Comment: I have selected  `Always Store` as setting

Comment: I have confiigred the `Default` Storage

Comment: @ShoaibAhmadGondal Please help me out with this I am fed up with this

Comment: I am searching for long and doing trial and error but no success

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145959/discussion-between-shoaib-ahmad-gondal-and-raut-darpan).

Comment: hey I am facing the same issue? Have you solved this issue?

Comment: yes, let me see if i can help you

Comment: Great. How did you solve this issue? I am getting XMPPError: feature-not-implemented - cancel

Comment: Should we add any extension provider to ProviderManager?

Comment: add the Archive message plugin, but offline message are not useful as they are in complicated formqat

Answer (score 1):

Reload again at plugin in OF 
    Monitoring Service
That all